# GIF color table formula

Tags: gif

In the GIF specifications noted here:

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

It gives the following formula for calculating the color table size:

3 x 2^(Size of Global Color Table+1).

Given this they use 'x' instead of '*', am I correct in assuming '^' does *not* mean XOR? If that is the case, what does '^' mean?

Thank you.

Comment: You can download the decoder logic and details from the following link - http://www.tune2wizard.com/gif-decoder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is commonly used for exponentiation, and `2` is a very common base for that.

The `Size of Color Table` variable is noted as a three-bit value, with in combination with the +1 means that the color table is between 2 and 256 colors. That indeed matches the GIF format.

(In C, you'd write this as `6 << Size_of_global_color_table`)

Comment: Not sure where to ask, but MSalters, I don't suppose I can use your suggestion for the C exponent code for any purpose (even commercial)? As I plan to hand over the finished (GIF reading) code an open source library which requires those permissions.

Comment: @SSight3: It's the canonical way to write such code. There's no intellectual property in that; so there's no permission needed. (More complex code would be covered by CC-SA license, see the SE legal statement)

Answer (score 0):

^ means power. So, it is 2 raise to the power of size of global colour table + 1. Basically, something as a base 2 can be powered to a value easily by left shift operation. So, you don't need pow() API. Just do the following . 2 << ( global_colour_table_size). For example, 2^3 is equal to 2 << 2. In general the formula is the following, 2^n is equal to 2<< (n-1).
You can download the decoder logic and details from the following link - http://www.tune2wizard.com/gif-decoder/

Answer (score 0):

C# code to get the number of colors and bytes from the Global Color Table

```
byte byt = imgBytes[10]; // get the first packed field byte
byt = (byte)(byt & 7); // low 3 bits only for the global color table size
int gctColors = (int)Math.Pow(2, byt + 1); // calculate number of colors
int gtcBytes = gctColors * 3; // 3 bytes per color
```